# could we create an object like implicit objects in JSP?

Tags: jsp

could we create an object like implicit objects in JSP? I just want to know because this  question was asked in the interview.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just subclass your JSP container to add new members that represent object instances that you want to expose to your pages or servlets.